# SKLabelNode or UILabel?

Tags: swift, uikit, sprite-kit

I read [the SKLabel class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKLabelNode_Ref/) and it says a SKLabelNode is a node that draws a string. I also read [the UILabel class reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Uikit/reference/UILabel_Class/index.html) and it says basically the same thing: it shows a static text view. How is this different from UILabel and which should I use? Is UILabel just for more ways of controlling the aspects of a text view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`SKLabelNode` is part of the Sprite Kit framework, and can only be added to a SKScene. `UILabel` is part of UIKit, and can be added to a UIView. If you are working on a general purpose app, you will want to be using UIKit and a UILabel; Sprite Kit is generally used for games.

Comment: show your code? remember that SpriteKit uses a different coordinate space, so if you're assigning a value derived from a UIKit frame or position you will get unexpected results.

Comment: @TheWobbuffet The size to fit behavior that you describe is all SKLabelNode knows how to do. You can't access its frame. All you should be doing is specifying the text of the label, its position, and specifying values for the nodes horizontalAlignmentMode and verticalAlignmentMode properties. When both are set to their respective center values, the label will be both vertically and horizontally centered at the coordinate you specify as the nodes position.